# const member function clarification needed

Tags: c++, constants, this, member-functions, function-qualifier

I'm a little confused as to why this code compiles and runs:

```
class A
{
private:
    int* b;
public:
    A() : b((int*)0xffffffff) {}
    int* get_b() const {return this->b;}
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    int *b = a.get_b();
    cout<<std::hex<<b<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output of running this code is `FFFFFFFF`as well... unexpected by me. Shouldn't `this->b` return `const int*` since it is in a const member function? and therefore the `return` line should generate a compiler-cast error for trying to cast `const int*` to `int*`

Obviously there's a gap here in my knowledge of what const member functions signify.
I'd appreciate if someone could help me bridge that gap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the member is an `int* const` (as seen from the const function), which is totally different.

The pointer is const, not the object pointed to.

Comment: Right. That explains it. So if b was int and get_b would try and return this->b then I would get the cast conversion error. Right?

Comment: If b was an int and you tried to return &b, the compiler would complain on that, yes.

Answer (score 2):

The `const` part of a member function just says that the function is allowed to be called when the `this` pointer (aka the object on which it is called) is const. It got nothing to do with the return value.

```
class A{
public:
  void non_const_func(){}
  void const_func() const {}
};

int main(){
  A a;
  a.const_func(); // works
  a.non_const_func(); // works too

  const A c_a;
  c_a.const_func(); // works again
  c_a.non_const_func(); // EEEK! Error, object is const but function isn't!
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The function returns an integer pointer by value - you can't change the class member it is a copy of via this value, so there is no const violation.

Answer (score 0):

Putting `const` after the function declaration like you have tells the compiler "Hey, I promise not to modfy `*this`!".  Your method is simply an accessor.

See [C++ FAQ LITE 18.10](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.10)